# How to AggregateAsync and Project for given MQL with Linq syntax?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-5

I have a collections called `storeinventories` in Mongodb. I am trying to perform following MQL query in the C# code.

The `storeinventories` collection has the following data model.

```
{
   "_id":"12938192831928",
   "ItemName":"Coke 20Oz",
   "Price":{
      "$numberInt":"-1"
   },
   "Cost":{
      "$numberInt":"-1"
   },
   "DeptId":"Coke", 
   "CreatedDate": "02/02/2020"
}
```

```
db.storeinventories.aggregate([ 
    {
        "$search": {
            "autocomplete": {
                "query": "item",
                "path": "ItemName",
                "fuzzy": {
                    "maxEdits": 2,
                    "prefixLength": 3
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "ItemName": 1,
            "Price": 1,
            "Cost": 1
        }
    }
])
```

This is what the `InventoryAutoComplete` class looks like. I am currently using `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` to ignore any field that I do not have in this class.

```
namespace inventory.service.Data
{
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class InventoryAutoComplete
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I am trying to find more Linq way to do my below query that I am doing to get the list from my query. Please feel free to give me better version of this if there is anything that we can improve with this.

I have two questions

1. How to Aggregate and Project like I have with MQL? I do currently use AggregateAsync to aggregate pipeline with MQL query. I was wondering if there is anytthing I can improve with the query.
2. Would Mongdb driver be smart enought to figureout to not fetch any other properties from server when I have `BsonIgnoreExtraElements` with a class?

```
var pipeline = new []
{
    new BsonDocument {
        {
            "$search",
            new BsonDocument( "autocomplete", new BsonDocument("path", "ItemName").AddRange(new BsonDocument("query", term)))

        }
    },
    new BsonDocument("$limit", 10)
    new BsonDocument
    { 
     
        {
            "$project", 
            new BsonDocument("ItemName", 1)
           //TODO: List all the properties that we have in the InventoryAutoComplete that we want to map. 
          // We do not want MongoDrive to fetch unneeded properties like `DeptId` and `CreatedDate`
          // Currently, the 'BsonIgnoreExtraElements' will take care of ignoring other needed properties
         
        }
    }
};

//StoreInventories is type 'IMongoCollection'
var list = await _inventoryContext
    .StoreInventories
    .AggregateAsync<InventoryAutoComplete>(pipeline);
```